# How to load and customize shared components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

Clicking `Show Hello message` should load the `HelloComponent` displaying "Hello" message on the main page.

Clicking `Show Product 1` should load `ProductComponent` customizing it so it displays "Product 1 Works!" message.

Clicking `Show Product 2` should load `ProductComponent` again but this time customizing it so it shows "Product 2 Works!".

How to implement this functionality? Here is the link to Stackblitz project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qkparn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

Comment: JFYI, the stackblitz project isn't building.

Comment: In demo both route and shared service includes you can check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obsjrv

Comment: The Stackblitz project should be running well now. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obsjrv) Firstly to run router you need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your component.

for communication between unrelated components there are several ways. These are selected based on your needs.

One of them is writing service . This is commonly choosen between components. You can share data with this service. But disadvantage of this is that when you refresh page you can't reach data anymore. If you want to keep data in service , you can stora data in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Another way is routing. Here your problem is that when you have multiple link with same component and different params. You can route but you can't notice to component that reinitialized then you need to set `onSameUrlNavigation` as reload and `shouldReuseRoute` of `routeReuseStrategy` as false.

You can use both way as communicaiton between unrelated components. For parent child component `@Input` method is easiest way to communicate